# Get ID of each row in modal by pressing edit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Here is my code of table. I want to get ID of each row in opened modal when press button "EDIT".  How can I send ID of selected row to modal? In my case bellow i am getting only first row ID.

Thank you for attention.

JS for modal form

```js
<script>
$(".btn[data-target='#myModal']").click(function() {
       var columnHeadings = $("thead th").map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
              }).get();
       columnHeadings.pop();
       var columnValues = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
       }).get();
  var modalBody = $('<div id="modalContent"></div>');
  var modalForm = $('<form role="form" name="modalForm" action="putYourPHPActionHere.php" method="post"></form>');
  $.each(columnHeadings, function(i, columnHeader) {
       var formGroup = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
       formGroup.append('<label for="'+columnHeader+'">'+columnHeader+'</label>');
       formGroup.append('<input class="form-control" name="'+columnHeader+i+'" id="'+columnHeader+i+'" value="'+columnValues[i]+'" />'); 
       modalForm.append(formGroup);
  });
  modalBody.append(modalForm);
  $('.modal-body').html(modalBody);
});
$('.modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function() {
   $('form[name="modalForm"]').submit();
});
</script>
```

```
      <table class="simple-little-table table" cellspacing='0'>

        <tr>
            <th><p>&#8470;</p></th>
            <th><p>Name, Surname</p></th>
            <th>Own number</th>
            <th>Company Number</th>
    </tr>


     <?php  
        $result =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE 1 and status=1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
    $id=$row["0"];
    echo '<tr>
                        <td><p>'.$row[1].' '.$row[2].'</p></td>
                        <td><p>'.$row[4].'</p></td>
                        <td><p>'.$row[5].'</p></td>';
    ?>
    <td><?php echo '<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" contenteditable="false" value=".$id.">'.$id.'</button>';?></td>

                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="">?   </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>

                <!--Here I am trying to echo ID-->
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"> sadasdas</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php
         }
         ?>
```

Here is picture of table
[image]

I need to get ID of row in modal
[image]

Comment: i didn't get your question. can you explain like what you want id of <tr> or the ID of row from db

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code? Where is that "Edit" button?

Comment: Fix your indentation and I will consider looking at it

Comment: @prabhjot i added picrures to make my question more clear.

Comment: @Vaidas I am trying to create working js, JS is my weak point...(

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov  you have to modify the answer according to your need but this will  work for you

Comment: you can ask if you need any help

Comment: @prabhjot sorry, but I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do . i am not using your data but assuming that you have enough understanding to use this according to your need.
Basically I am just using a trick.

```
<table>
<?php $sr=1;
while(your condition){?>
<tr>
<td id="td_<?=$sr++;?>">value you want in model</td>
<td><button id="<?=$sr;?>">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

you will get something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="td_1"></td> <!--see the id of this td and button--->
</td><button class="myclass" id="1"></button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="td_2"></td>
</td><button class="myclass" id="2"></button></td>
</tr>
```

now use this jquery

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
 var btn_id =  $(this).attr('id'); //getting the btn's id
var row_id = "#td_"+btn_id; // by this you got the id of that td
$('#id_in_modal_where_you_need_this').text($(row_id).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Good idea to use classes, will try it now.

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov did it worked for you? if it worked then you can upvote and mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getValue(id){
   $('#myModalLabel').text(id);
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

and call this function on button click
instead of using this

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" contenteditable="false" value=".$id.">
```

use

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick='getValue(".$id.");' contenteditable="false" value=".$id.">
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your code is passing value to modal form. I need this id to write it in query, but id in your code is vissible only on header of modal.

Comment: which query you are talking about?

Comment: Ops my fault. I forget to echo it. It is working perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it is not totally what I need.

Here is my query  in modal 
`<?php

    $s = mysql_query("Select * from MY_TABLE where id = $id");
    while($k = mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
     
    ?>`

Comment: In content I want to get name of selected row.

`<input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $k['AD']."sds"; ?>" />`

Still getting first id of table.

Comment: so you can pass name instead of id in getValue method

Comment: Yeap i can pass only 1 value in  getValue method, name was just example. I need to get many columns. Thats why i used query and with while used fetch_array

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create html for modal for each row, but instead just create one modal, which will be used when every row is clicked.
Then, using jquery in click method you can set different fields for modal, such as id or something else, like this for example:

```
    $("btn").click(function(event) {
        id = event.target.id;
        $(#myModalIdField).text = id;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

first, give a table `id="name"`,
use your own table and data and if ur using a database or normal table; 
use button modal as -

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Your data </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Your Data </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='getValue(".$rindex.")' contenteditable="false" value=".$rindex.""> </td>
                  <div class=" modal fade" id="myModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <!-- Modal Header -->
                            <div class="modal-header" id="myModalLabel">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter Remarks:</h4>
                                <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>-->
                            </div>
                            <!-- Modal body -->
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="comment">Remarks:</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" name="msub" id="" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Use this jquery :

```
var table = document.getElementById('table'), rindex;
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function getValue(rindex) {
        rindex = this.rowIndex;
        $('#myModalLabel').text(rindex);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code will show the row number when you click any button, please use bootstrap or your own css